# how skip a page in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I started using `Scrapy` recently.

I used below code in command line

```
scrapy shell https://website.com/portal/login
```

and then I enterd below

```
 response.css('::text')
```

**output**

```
[<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::text()' data='Transferring to the website...'>, <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::text()' data=' در ﺣﺎل اﻧﺘﻘﺎل ﺑﻪ ﺳﺎﯾﺖ ﻣﻮرد ﻧﻈﺮ ﻫﺴﺘﯿﺪ...'>, <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::text()' data='var _this = this;\n\n  function _typeof...'>]
```

When I use Web Browser(and above with scrapy) before the login page appers another page with `transferring to the website...` message in center of it is opens.

My question is how can I prevent this? How can I skip this loading page and when I entered the `login url` in `scrapy shell` command I get the login page instead of loading page?

Comment: these loading pages are usually from CDN servers or from similar anti-bot systems, you cannot skip it directly, they are sending some javascript code to determine if it's a browser that's requesting the data or not. To solve the JS puzzle with python can be difficult. I suggest using selenium if you can.

Comment: @jenishSakhiya Does it possible in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I don't think it is, as BeautifulSoup is irrelevant when it comes to executing javascript, as far as I know, it only parses HTML DOM.